# C++ class member function with reference return type

Tags: c++, reference, this-pointer

I am a newbie to programming and C++.
I'm confused how reference works differently here.

The code below outputs `0 5` but removing the `&` from `A &GotObj()` would output `0 0`. Why didn't the second case output `0 5`?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int val;
    A(int n=0) {
        val = n;

    }
    A &GetObj() {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    cout << a.val << endl;
    a.GetObj() = 5;
    cout << a.val << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just had a serious wtf moment until I marked the c'tor as explicit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> **Case 1: A GetObj()**

- lets Create object of Class A :

> A a;

- suppose this objects memory location is **0x87965432**. Now, when you call function of object a by
  **a.GetObj()** then it returns a temporary object whose memory location will be completely different then  Class A's object a, lets say **0x98672345**. now if you assign value 5 by

> a.GetObj() = 5

- then you are assigning value 5 to the object located at memory location **0x98672345**. now, you are going to print **val** variable of object which is located at memory location 0x87965432. thats why it will print 0.

> **Case 2: A &GetObj()**

- as explained in Case 1, if you create object by

> A a;

- lets consider its memory location **0x87965432**. now when you call function GetObj, by a.GetObj(), then return object will be of same memory location **0x87965432**, as its concept of return by Referance. now assigning value 5 to this object,

> a.GetObj() = 5

will reflect effect in object a. and now printing value of variable **val** will be as expected 5.

Comment: That's factually wrong. C++ is strongly typed, you can't just assign willy nilly to objects without having an appropriate assignment operator.

Comment: @StoryTeller, if you consider memory wise, then there is only one variable val, then by assigning a.GetObj() = 5, it will assign 5 to val only.

Comment: Until you add a `double` member, and your explanation goes out the window. While the example still works.

Comment: yeah, in case of double member, C++ strongly type concept comes into picture. however for this question, its adequate to make sense.

Comment: @Nishant  Your Answer Help me :)

Comment: @Nishant Thanks a lot! I think I get it now. return of *this creates a temporary object whose location is different but has same val value.

Answer (score 1):

When you return by value the expression `a.GetObj()` just creates a temporary. Assigning then only changes the value of that temporary.

Answer (score 1):

This of a reference as just a pointer with a slightly different syntax.
When `GetObj` is defined as

```
A& GetObj() { return *this: }
```

it returns a reference (i.e. a pointer) to a.
Then, the assignment

```
a.GetObj() = 5
```

effectively invokes the assignment operator of `a` with the argument 5, which changes the value of a to 5.

But if you define `GetObj()` as

```
A GetObj { return *this; }
```

it returns a completely new temporary object that has the same value as a.
So when you later assign 5 to it, it doesn't change the value of a.

Comment: There is no assignment operator of `A` taking an `int`.